# Is it safe to keep reference, but not assigning data to an actual variable?

Tags: go, reference, slice

I want to keep a list of references in a slice, but I couldn't fine any resource online that explains if keeping reference without assigning to a variable is safe or not?

I mean, is it possible that the OS write something in the referenced addresses that is not expected by the programmer?

Here is an example code:

```golang
type ListItem [8]uint64

list := make([]*ListItem, 0)

list = append(list, &ListChunk{})
list = append(list, &ListChunk{})
list = append(list, &ListChunk{})
```

In other words, is it guaranteed that Items in the slice named `list` stay same while program is running, no matter how long it takes to run?

Comment: Keeping a pointer _somewhere_ ensures the pointed value will not be garbage collected. Your Go runtime will not write anything to it arbitrarily. What other apps do in your operating system is beyond your app's reach. Does this satisfy you?

Comment: If an OS arbitrarily modified memory allocated to a running program, no software would ever work on that OS.

Comment: @icza So, as I'm keeping references in a slice, and as Charlie mentioned, a slice is also a variable, my code is safe and garbage collector doesn't free the memory unexpectedly. That is what I wanted to make sure of. Thank you!

Comment: @moo.duwayne Addressable expressions act as variables, but this is not a requirement. Storing the pointers in a map for example also prevents them from getting garbage collected, yet values stored in maps are not addressable.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

in your case probably no (the references will remain unchanged) but it depends also on what your program does to it :

The Go runtime doesn't change the references (pointers) stored in a slice for the lifetime of the program But in ONE CONDITION:
-you don't reassign  the slice or its elements pointers (array of [8]uint64) in a function . As long as you don't reassign new values to the elements of the slice, the references will remain unchanged.

Comment: Sorry my English is not good so here is what I understand: by reassigning you mean executing `list = make([]*ListItem, 0)` or `list[1] = &ListChunk{}` at the end of program, right? So in first case whole items in the slice will gets free by gc, and in second case only list[1] will gets free. right?